# Ocelot Aggregator doesn't work for post method

Tags: c#, http-post, .net-6.0, api-gateway, ocelot

Good afternoon community. 
I present my case and then I ask the question.
In ocelot.json I have the corresponding configuration to consume the microservice method through post. 
I execute the request according to the configured route and it responds correctly.
Then I define an aggregate, because I need to process the response before sending it back to the client but it throws me a 404. I think I have the route configured correctly, but I can't find the problem. 
Can you help me?

ocelot.json

```
{
  "Aggregates": [
    {
      "RouteKeys": [ "account" ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/login",
      "Aggregator": "LoginEmployeeAggregator"
    }
  ],
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/employees/loginEmployee",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 44305
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/account",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post" ],
      "Key": "account"
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7014"
  }
}
```

LoginEmployeeAggregator.cs

```
    public class LoginEmployeeAggregator : IDefinedAggregator
    {
        public async Task<DownstreamResponse> Aggregate(List<HttpContext> responses)
        {
            if (responses.Any(r => r.Items.Errors().Count > 0))
            {
                return new DownstreamResponse(null, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, (List<Header>)null, null);
            }

            var userResponseContent = await responses[0].Items.DownstreamResponse().Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserDTO>>(userResponseContent);
            var postByUserString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users);

            var stringContent = new StringContent(postByUserString)
            {
                Headers = { ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json") }
            };
            return new DownstreamResponse(stringContent, HttpStatusCode.OK, new List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>(), "OK");

        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
//...
            builder.Services.AddOcelot()//Registered 'AddOcelot' service.
                .AddSingletonDefinedAggregator<LoginEmployeeAggregator>();
//...
```

when call post to https://localhost:7014/api/account -> ok(200)
when call post to https://localhost:7014/api/login -> error(404)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) --> "Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem."

Comment: I have reformulated my question. Thank you for your clarification

Answer (score 1):

Ocelot supports Http GET method only. See documentation: [Aggregation only supports the GET HTTP Verb.](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/requestaggregation.html#gotcha-s-further-info)